# K-means which normalization fits

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, k-means

Hi am working on a business dataset, where I want to group the participant in k-means based on some features.

The problem is I have to create this features upfront, so that I combine different features for a big matrix, e.g. I based it on the buys in a product group:

```
dfProduct
participitants   ProductA  ProductB ... ProductE
A               1            2     ...   1000
B               1            5     ...   1
```

and another feature matrix, e.g. based on the store they bought it:

```
dfStore
participitants   StoreA  StoreB
A               1001         200     
B               1000          5
```

This two (and more) dataframe will be joined together, that I have one big dataframe to run k-means.

The risk I see is that some features (as example) have high influence for the clustering, so that e.g. lead by StoreA , participants A and B will get into the same cluster, this does not make sense on the business perspective. I do not want to have "unfair" features. 
Which preprocessing step (in terms of python) would be the right approach for me? MinMaxScaler?

Comment: Don't mix such variables. Most likely k-means is the wrong tool for your problem then. It will not be solved just by using some library function.

Comment: after experimenting with kmeans and labbeling it, I also have the same feeling, what is a better approach?

Comment: You first need to understand the problem that you are trying to solve, then choose a method than can solve this exact problem ("clustering" is way too vague). Don't try to guess the right algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just worried about the distance measure in the clustering, any type of scaling/normalization should work. I would recommend a [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), but [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) or [Normalizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer) should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must use k-modes(an extension of k-means) for categorical problems. I had a similar business problem and I used K-modes clustering algorithm and solved my issue. Below is the URL that will help you understand the algorithm. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b39_vipRkUo